# How to use jQuery in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have some fields in my view. i have a field `username` which is made by `firstname and lastname like username = firstname_lastname`

My code:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('maxlength'=>255));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('maxlength'=>255,'onchange'=>'$(#User_username).val($('#User_firstname').val()+"_"+this.value())'));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'username');</div>
    </div>
```

This is working when i select `firstname` then `lastname` but when i change `firstname` after creating `username` then `username` not changes accordingly. please help.

Comment: Add onchange for first name also?

Comment: @vijaykumar: i have already added this in lastname because both firstname and lastname are needed  for username and I don't want to write same code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to added same onChange for firstname also

```
<div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('maxlength'=>255, 'onchange'=>'$(#User_username).val($('#User_firstname').val()+"_"+this.value())'));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('maxlength'=>255,'onchange'=>'$(#User_username).val($('#User_firstname').val()+"_"+this.value())'));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'username');</div>
    </div>
```

Or you can add your own java script

```
<div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('maxlength'=>255, 'onchange'=>'updateUsername()'));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('maxlength'=>255,'onchange'=>'updateUsername()'));</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div>echo $form->textField($model,'username');</div>
    </div>
<script>
   function updateUsername()
   {
      $(#User_username).val($('#User_firstname').val()+"_"+this.value());
   }
</script>
```

Or if you want to use yii scripts just try [this](http://www.larryullman.com/2014/08/18/adding-javascript-to-a-page-in-yii/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes in the first selector and have the wrong type in the second.

Change

```
'onchange'=>'$(#User_username).val($('#User_firstname').val()+"_"+this.value())'
```

To

```
'onchange'=>'$("#User_username").val($("#User_firstname").val()+"_"+this.value())'
```